# Querydsl 4 StringTemplate creation

Tags: java, expression, querydsl, stringtemplate

Is there an alternative to StringTemplate.create("") in QueryDsl 4?

In version 3 i could write things like this:

```
final StringExpression createdMonthYear = StringTemplate.create("to_char(CREATED_DATETIME, 'YYYY.MM')");
```

But since Querydsl 4 this won't work.

**EDIT:**

Nevermind. I found the answer...

```
final StringExpression createdMonthYear = Expressions.asString("to_char(CREATED_DATETIME, 'YYYY.MM')");
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP found

```
final StringExpression createdMonthYear = Expressions.asString("to_char(CREATED_DATETIME,
'YYYY.MM')");
```